# gnuplot: use header column names as line keys

Tags: gnuplot

Is this possible?

If I write:

```
plot "foo.csv" every ::1 with lines
```

I'll get the data.  Then, I write:

```
set key outside; plot "foo.csv" every ::1 with lines
```

If the first line of "foo.csv" is:

```
xaxis,line1_name,line2_name,...
```

Then how would I (minimalistically as possible) achieve a plot such that the names in the legend correspond to the header column names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In gnuplot check `help columnhead` and the links there.

***Code:**

```
### columnhead
reset session

set datafile separator ","
set key top left autotitle columnhead

$Data <<EOD
x, Col2, Col3, Col4
11,  12,   13,   14
21,  22,   23,   24
31,  32,   33,   34
41,  42,   43,   44
EOD

plot \
    $Data u 1:2 w lp, \
    ''    u 1:3 w lp, \
    ''    u 1:4 w lp
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]